# Registering custom class with parameter HTTPContextAccessor AND another parameter is not compiling

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, startup, asp.net-core-3.1

According to this it should automatically pass in the IHttpContextAccessor when resolving the dependency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I have this in my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(_configuration);

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSingleton<IServerConnectionHelper>(new ServerConnectionHelper(_configuration));
```

This is how my ServerConnectionHelper is trying to get the HttpContextAccessor:

```
    public class ServerConnectionHelper : IServerConnectionHelper
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public ServerConnectionHelper(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
    }
```

Now I sorta understand why it is complaining about "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'httpContentAccessor', but in the example from Microsoft does not have one either.

The Microsoft example shows that it uses AddTransient, but when I attempt to switch to that I can not seem to figure out how to pass the context into the registration for my ServerConnectionHelper class.

Any DI experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

As usual I figure it out right after asking the question. That's why I come here!

services.AddSingleton(new ServerConnectionHelper(_configuration));

needed to be
services.AddTransient<IServerConnectionHelper, ServerConnectionHelper>();

As usual I was making it too hard on myself